# Reassign object through its constructor and "this" keyword

Tags: java, constructor, this

I am trying to expand my program to allow different NPCs with a similar code base. I want to have a super class NPC with with various subclasses for each creature. Here I will call them Enemy1, Enemy2, and Enemy3.

I also want to assign any given NPC to a variable via `NPC enemy = new NPC(enemyID);`, where "enemyID" is an integer denoting the NPC's in-game id (let Enemy1's ID = 1, Enemy2's = 2, Enemy3's =3).

Even if this works, is it ok in practice (I haven't tested it just yet since the actual code will have more in-depth features):

```
public class NPC
{
    public NPC(int id)
    {
        switch (id)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                this = new Enemy1();
                break;
            }
            case 3:
            {
                this = new Enemy3();
                break;
            }
            case 3:
            {
                this = new Enemy3();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    //Various default and shared methods will follow
}

public class Enemy1 extends NPC
{
    //Various variables specific to this enemy
    public Enemy1()    //LOL
    {
        //Assign default values
    }
    //Default methods overwritten and enemy-specific methods go here
}
```

I'm not sure if that would compile since I don't have the full implementation yet, but I just want to know if an object can self-reassign in this manner, and if that is an OK programming choice. If you need clarification, let me know, and please give me reasons in your answers so I can learn instead of just getting a yes/no answer (I am self-taught, so feedback is especially helpful).

Comment: Try using a factory method for it, where you return the newly constructed class.

Comment: What do you think `this` is?

Comment: `this` is a keyword used by an object to represent itself. However, here it doesn't apply since the answer does not need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have it currently, it won't compile. The pattern you're reaching for is called a [*factory*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern), where instead of creating an object directly, you call a "factory" function with various parameters, and that function creates and returns the appropriate object.

A very, very basic example could look something like this:

```
public class Enemy1 extends NPC {
}
public class Enemy2 extends NPC {
}

public class NPCFactory {
    public static NPC makeNPC(int npcType) {
        if(npcType==1){ return new Enemy1(); }
        elif(npcType==2) {return new Enemy2(); }
    }
}
```

---

As your code grows, you'll likely want to replace the `int npcType` with a proper `Enum`, to make your code's behavior clearer for future developers (i.e. your future self). You can also add as many parameters to the factory as neccessary, allowing it to create a fully-functional NPC with whatever parameters you need it to have, all in one go.

Comment: So in my previous example, the code assigning the NPC would be `NPC enemy = NPCFactory.makeNPC(npcType);` based on your example, with implementations of each NPC in the top of your source?

Comment: Exactly. Another common pattern is to put some sort of relevant information into the factory itself, in which case you'd want to make an `NPCFactory` and then use it over and over to create NPCs--in that case, you'd want to take out the `static` declaration from the `makeNPC` method.